# How to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\pi t)\text{d}t$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

How to show that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\pi t)\text{d}t$ is divergent?

It makes sense that it is divergent... but is there a way to show this with the comparison theorem? I was thinking that this integral is always less than $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{d}t$ which diverges, but I can't conclude from that that the original function diverges... insight appreciated

Comment: The comparison theorem only works for nonnegative functions, so it will not help you. What you can do here is just compute the antiderivative and show the integral diverges directly from the definition.

Comment: Compute the integral on suitable $\pi$ length intervals. You will get $2-2+2-2...$

Comment: @mark so take a double limit? as the bottom goes to infinity and the top goes to infinity?

Comment: @HerbEnthusiast No, just show the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ diverges, this is sufficient.

Comment: ...because of symmetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$\int_{-N}^N\cos(\pi t)\mathrm{d}t=[\tfrac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi t)]_{-N}^N=\tfrac{2}{\pi}\sin(\pi N)$$has no $N\to\infty$ limit on $[0,\,\infty)$, the original improper integral diverges.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, with $n\in \mathbb N$, we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-n}^{n} \cos(\pi t)dt=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\frac12-2n}^{\frac12+2n} \cos(\pi t)dt=\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} \cos(\pi t)dt>0$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: You forgot to write the additional $\sin$ term, making it seem like $2/\pi$ doesn't exist!

Comment: @Vilakshan My aim is to obtain the result by symmetry condition, we don't need to integrate.